# Get NSAttributed String color on tap SWIFT

Tags: ios, swift, uitapgesturerecognizer, nsmutableattributedstring, nsmutablestring

I'm using a `UITextView` which contains multiple colors. I'm using `NSMutableAttributedString` for this. I'm fetching the words by tapping on the word inside the TextView in console. Now I want to fetch the color of the attributed string along with the word. I've found no resource in Swift. Everything I found was in Objective-C. Here is my `UITapGestureRecognizer` handler function.

```
@objc func myMethodToHandleTap(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    let textView = sender.view as! UITextView
    let location: CGPoint = sender.location(in: textView)
    let position: CGPoint = CGPoint(x: location.x, y: location.y)
    let tapPosition: UITextPosition? = textView.closestPosition(to: position)

    if tapPosition != nil {
        let textRange: UITextRange? = textView.tokenizer.rangeEnclosingPosition(tapPosition!, with: UITextGranularity.word, inDirection: UITextDirection(rawValue: 1))
        if textRange != nil && textColor == UIColor.red
        {
            let tappedWord: String? = textView.text(in: textRange!)
            print("Color : RED , tapped word : ", tappedWord!)
        }
        else if textRange != nil && textColor == UIColor.green
        {
            let tappedWord: String? = textView.text(in: textRange!)

            print("Color : GREEN , tapped word : ", tappedWord!)
        }
        else {
            print("empty space")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you adding word color programmatic than check tap word range and match with you applied range then you can easily find the color of the tapped word.

**textColor** where you assign a value before compare?

[This will help you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19844336/is-it-possible-to-get-a-listing-of-attributes-and-ranges-for-an-nsmutableattribu)

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the color this way:

```
if 
    let tapPosition = tapPosition,
    let characterIndex = textView.offset(from: textView.beginningOfDocument, to: tapPosition)
    let textColor = textView.attributedText.attribute(.foregroundColor, at: characterIndex, effectiveRange: nil) as? UIColor 
{
    //Do what you want with text color
}
```